# if word exists, remove

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a list of ETF names and their tickers, however it looks like ETF name is sometimes duplicated due to the addition of the word "etf" at the end:

```
Ishares Global Tech
Ishares Global Tech etf
Ishares Edge Msci Usa Momentum Factor
Ishares Edge Msci Usa Momentum Factor etf
```

How can I write it such that if ETF name ends with "etf" then extract is taken out of output?

Currently my query looks something like this:

```
select initcap(display_name) name, upper(symbol) as symbol, sum(amount) aum 
from table 
where regexp_instr(lower(display_name),'isha?r?e?s')>0
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `' etf'` only occurs once, you can do:

```
select split_part(display_name, ' etf', 1)
```

Alternatively, I would go for `case`:

```
select (case when display_name like '% etf'
             then left(display_name, len(display_name) - 4)
             else display_name
        end) as new_display_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use REPLACE like below:

```
select REPLACE(display_name,' ETF','')
from table
where RIGHT(display_name,4) = ' ETF'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use regex_replace

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(display_name, '^.*(etf)$', '', 'i')
from table
```

I realised you wanted to filter out anything ending with 'etf' so then you can do

```
select initcap(display_name) name, upper(symbol) as symbol, sum(amount) aum 
from table 
where display_name !~* '^.*etf$'
group by 1,2
```